# Detecting if Chrome is in the foreground after computer resumes from idle state

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a chrome extension that (among other things) tracks how much time you spend on various sites. I'm using the chrome.idle API to track when the computer goes idle/resumes in order to stop and start the timers.

The problem I'm having is when the computer resumes from idle, my timer is starting back up even if Chrome isn't the active application on the user's computer. Here's my code:

```
chrome.idle.onStateChanged.addListener(function(newState){

  if (newState == "active") {
   //user resumes activity after being locked/idle:
    chrome.tabs.query({ currentWindow: true, active: true }, function (tabs) {
        processTab(tabs[0]);
    });

  } 
});
```

I've tried both: `chrome.tabs.query({ currentWindow: true, active: true})` and `chrome.tabs.query({ lastFocusedWindow: true, active: true`  and both are returning the window/active tab even when Chrome itself is not the active application on the computer.

How do I assure that Chrome is indeed the active/foreground application in this case?

Comment: Try chrome.windows.getAll and check each window's `focused` property.

Comment: That worked, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Based on wOxxOm's comment above, the solution was to iterate through all the window objects and check the focused property:

```
 chrome.windows.getAll(null, function (windows){
        windows.forEach(function(window){

            if(window.focused){
                chrome.tabs.query({ windowId: window.id, active: true }, function (tabs) {
                     processTab(tabs[0]);
                });

            }


        });

    });
```